# How to assign cpu cores to multiple instances of a program with arguments using tasket

Tags: linux, multithreading, bash, unix, parallel-processing

## Problem description

I am trying to run **7** instances of `models_test` on a  **6** cores machine. For this purpose I was using the following script. Task number **7** is the most demanding in terms of computation.

```
#!/bin/bash

./models_test tfidf.db output/ input/ 1 10 &
./models_test tfidf.db output/ input/ 11 20 &
./models_test tfidf.db output/ input/ 21 30 &
./models_test tfidf.db output/ input/ 31 40 &
./models_test tfidf.db output/ input/ 41 50 &
./models_test tfidf.db output/ input/ 51 60 &
./models_test tfidf.db output/ input/ 61 70
```

---

`./models_test` takes **5** arguments:

1. database
2. output path
3. input path
4. id 1
5. id 2

---

### taskset

I wanted to run the same **7** instances by using the [taskset](https://littledaemons.wordpress.com/2009/01/22/cpu-affinity-and-taskset/) command as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Cpus are identified by `{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`

     taskset -c 0 ./models_test tfidf.db output/ input/ 1 10 &
     taskset -c 1 ./models_test tfidf.db output/ input/ 11 20 &
     taskset -c 2 ./models_test tfidf.db output/ input/ 21 30 &
     taskset -c 3 ./models_test tfidf.db output/ input/ 31 40 &
     taskset -c 3 ./models_test tfidf.db output/ input/ 41 50 &
     taskset -c 4 ./models_test tfidf.db output/ input/ 51 60 &
     taskset -c 5 ./models_test tfidf.db output/ input/ 61 70
```

---

### Questions

- Am I doing the job correctly in `taskset` by dividing the **7** tasks on the **6** cores?
- Will the first script assign the **7** seven tasks automatically on the **6** cores?

Comment: Hard to see given the scope of what you're attempting that you can't get access to an 8 core machine. I think your time would be better spent asking around for some time on a properly sized machine. OR did you try skipping `taskset` and just let the OS divy up the work. It's actually pretty good at that task. ;-) . Good luck.!

Comment: @shellter is my question that dumb? looooooooool sorry man

Comment: I hope I didn't jynx you getting answers for others, but usually if someone has a better idea they chime in. The other thought that I had was that you run your taskset 0-5 and then don't use taskset for 6, but let the OS divide that job up among all CPU. As task 6 is your biggest, once the others clear out, you'll get the a full 100% CPU working on it. (I don't suppose this code is designed to be run across multiple CPU at the same time).

Comment: My experience with this sort of project is to do some tests. Cut the data to 1/4 size and try several ideas. Carefully run the test, being sure to not let system cached data trick you into thinking one test is much faster than another. (You have to find a way to clear the cache before running each test, maybe read a humongus file to `/dev/null` ? Not sure, you'll have to goggle around for what is best for your environment). Good luck.

Comment: And, actually a well constructed problem definition, so you get my  upvote (FWIW). Finally, my early comments where written in haste, and only meant to give you an alternate "set-of-eyes" on your problem. Sorry if they were rude. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I often hit similar problems. Instead of using taskset I use nice:

```
parallel --nice 11 ./models_test tfidf.db output/ input/ {} '{= $_+=9 =}' ::: {1..60..10} &
./models_test tfidf.db output/ input/ 61 70
wait
```